# Standard deviation and mean of sampled data problem

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have a query with my teacher's "self-made" question:

> A random variable $Y$ has a normal distribution with a mean of $\mu$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma$. Given that in a large sample, 10% of the values of $Y$ exceed 17.24 and 25% exceed 14.37, find $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

I am taught in order to do this we must apply the standardizing formula and create two simultaneous equations using the given data. However, since the data is from a large SAMPLE I realized I must use $\sigma/\sqrt n$, which gives me 3 variables to solve for in two equations. We have only been given prior questions which weren't of sample data meaning $\sqrt n$ wasn't required. Is this question correct as we have been asked to calculate the mean and standard deviation of a sample which is impossible if I am not given $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key word is "large"; the sample may be taken as identically distributed to the population, so sample size is irrelevant. Then the two $z$-score equations arise:
$$\frac{17.24-\mu}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(0.9)=1.282$$
$$\frac{14.37-\mu}{\sigma}=\Phi^{-1}(0.75)=0.6745$$
These may be solved to yield
$$\mu=11.18\qquad\sigma=4.724$$

Comment: So you are stating that since the sample is so large, it is technically identical to the entire population?

Comment: @Jan _Yes._ ${}$